# Count frequency of Russian words

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am learning Russian now and I thought to analyse poetry and literature by using a macro to display the frequency of words.

I found this website: https://word.tips.net/T000879_Determining_Word_Frequency.html

I modified the code for modern version:

```
Sub Frequentie()
'
' Frequentie Macro
'
'
    Dim SingleWord As String           'Raw word pulled from doc
    Const maxwords = 9000              'Maximum unique words allowed
    Dim Words(maxwords) As String      'Array to hold unique words
    Dim Freq(maxwords) As Integer      'Frequency counter for unique words
    Dim WordNum As Integer             'Number of unique words
    Dim ByFreq As Boolean              'Flag for sorting order
    Dim ttlwds As Long                 'Total words in the document
    Dim Excludes As String             'Words to be excluded
    Dim Found As Boolean               'Temporary flag
    Dim j As Integer                   'Temporary variables
    Dim k As Integer                   '
    Dim l As Integer                   '
    Dim Temp As Integer                '
    Dim tword As String                '

    ' Set up excluded words
    Excludes = "[the][a][of][is][to][for][this][that][by][be][and][are]"

    ' Find out how to sort
    ByFreq = True
    ans = InputBox$("Sort by WORD or by FREQ?", "Sort order", "WORD")
    If ans = "" Then End
    If UCase(ans) = "WORD" Then
        ByFreq = False
    End If
    
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    System.Cursor = wdCursorWait
    WordNum = 0
    ttlwds = ActiveDocument.Words.Count

    ' Control the repeat
    For Each aword In ActiveDocument.Words
        SingleWord = Trim(LCase(aword))
        If SingleWord < "a" Or SingleWord > "z" Then SingleWord = ""    'Out of range?
        If InStr(Excludes, "[" & SingleWord & "]") Then SingleWord = "" 'On exclude list?
        If Len(SingleWord) > 0 Then
            Found = False
            For j = 1 To WordNum
                If Words(j) = SingleWord Then
                    Freq(j) = Freq(j) + 1
                    Found = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            If Not Found Then
                WordNum = WordNum + 1
                Words(WordNum) = SingleWord
                Freq(WordNum) = 1
            End If
            If WordNum > maxwords - 1 Then
                j = MsgBox("The maximum array size has been exceeded. Increase maxwords.", vbOKOnly)
                
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        ttlwds = ttlwds - 1
        StatusBar = "Remaining: " & ttlwds & "     Unique: " & WordNum
    Next aword

    ' Now sort it into word order
    For j = 1 To WordNum - 1
        k = j
        For l = j + 1 To WordNum
            If (Not ByFreq And Words(1) < Words(k)) Or (ByFreq And Freq(1) > Freq(k)) Then k = 1
        Next l
        If k <> j Then
            tword = Words(j)
            Words(j) = Words(k)
            Words(k) = tword
            Temp = Freq(j)
            Freq(j) = Freq(k)
            Freq(k) = Temp
        End If
        StatusBar = "Sorting: " & WordNum - j
    Next j

    ' Now write out the results
    tmpName = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName
    Documents.Add Template:=tmpName, NewTemplate:=False
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.ClearAll
    With Selection
        For j = 1 To WordNum
            .TypeText Text:=Trim(Str(Freq(j))) & vbTab & Words(j) & vbCrLf
        Next j
    End With
    System.Cursor = wdCursorNormal
    j = MsgBox("There were " & Trim(Str(WordNum)) & _
        " different words ", vbOKOnly, "Finished")
End Sub
```

The problem I have is with the line

```
If SingleWord < "a" Or SingleWord > "z" Then SingleWord = ""    'Out of range?
```

I want this to remain but to only include Russian words. I can't fit the Russian letters there (being а until я).

Furthermore I would like it to sort alphabetically in Russian.

Comment: You  might try: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/concordance-of-every-word-by-pageline-number/bf072171-8870-4cbf-8460-0bdb3832f3b0

Comment: you might as well just think if you really need word and vba for that. You might as well use this, for example, to count word frequency: https://www.somacon.com/p568.php